# JasperReports : Conditional Style error " parameter not found "?

Tags: jasper-reports

I want to use conditional style in one of my reports to change the color based on a condition but it doesn't work at all.

I tried to use it with `<parameter></parameter>`, `<field></field>` and with `<variable></variable>` in all cases i get the same error :

**(parameter or field or variable) not found !**

here is my code JRXML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="UserDepart" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="15289120-bdf0-4edd-905c-647999c3c0cc">
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.style.evaluation.time.enabled" value="true"/>
    <style name="table">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table_TH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#00FFFF">
        <box>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <!-- Here Is The Probleme !!! -->
    <style name="table_CH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FF6666">
        <box>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
        <conditionalStyle>
            <conditionExpression><![CDATA[$P{color}.equalsIgnoreCase( "o" )]]></conditionExpression>
            <style/>
        </conditionalStyle>
    </style>
    <style name="table_TD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <box>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <subDataset name="New Dataset 1" uuid="2c012e5d-0895-4ef1-8b47-20fd8c6b281f">
        <queryString>
            <![CDATA[]]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="nom" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="prenom" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="profil" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="tauxCorrect" class="java.lang.Float"/>
        <field name="progres" class="java.lang.Long"/>
    </subDataset>
    <parameter name="DS1" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource"/>
    <parameter name="logo" class="java.lang.Object" isForPrompting="false"/>
    <!-- Here Is The Parameter i'm using !!! -->
    <parameter name="color" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="departement" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <variable name="colorVar" class="java.lang.String">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$P{color}]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="42" splitType="Stretch">
            <image>
                <reportElement x="1" y="1" width="127" height="21" uuid="d12193fc-3939-4a94-81c9-28f6e648566a"/>
                <imageExpression><![CDATA["C:\\Icons\\logo.png"]]></imageExpression>
            </image>
            <image>
                <reportElement x="388" y="0" width="167" height="32" uuid="4f149815-5c04-4b13-a520-e30202556d92"/>
                <imageExpression><![CDATA[$P{logo}]]></imageExpression>
            </image>
        </band>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="51" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="419" y="0" width="136" height="30" uuid="efb55c6b-c6b5-4855-8111-fc621e280922"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="18"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{departement}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="1" y="0" width="418" height="30" uuid="54fd910a-b9ab-441a-b7e5-a332f67b0504"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="18"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Etat d'avancement des utilisateurs du département :]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </pageHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="151" splitType="Stretch">
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement key="table" style="table" x="2" y="2" width="552" height="147" uuid="1e15cf18-8adf-4bad-9339-04deb8240c82"/>
                <jr:table xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="New Dataset 1" uuid="5ccdd061-c1c3-46a0-bc92-af14bda9b14a">
                        <datasetParameter name="REPORT_DATA_SOURCE">
                            <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{DS1}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
                        </datasetParameter>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:column width="104" uuid="faddf5bb-759d-4efc-9a3e-9cf16b8cbda2">
                        <jr:columnHeader style="table_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                            <box>
                                <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                            </box>
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="104" height="30" uuid="795dac43-0ff0-482c-89a0-7dac3b27d513"/>
                                <textElement>
                                    <font size="10"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[Nom]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="table_TD" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                            <box>
                                <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                            </box>
                            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="104" height="30" uuid="195d51a0-9e45-4201-ad67-d3026ce2e72c"/>
                                <textElement>
                                    <font size="10"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{nom}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="111" uuid="8a8bc20b-f8b4-45a6-9cbd-68b4a7391426">
                        <jr:columnHeader style="table_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                            <box>
                                <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                            </box>
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="111" height="30" uuid="795dac43-0ff0-482c-89a0-7dac3b27d513"/>
                                <textElement>
                                    <font size="10"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[Prenom]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="table_TD" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                            <box>
                                <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                            </box>
                            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="111" height="30" uuid="195d51a0-9e45-4201-ad67-d3026ce2e72c"/>
                                <textElement>
                                    <font size="10"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{prenom}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="102" uuid="657d2155-3e2f-4f41-ba0a-a17a76598491">
                        <jr:columnHeader style="table_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                            <box>
                                <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                            </box>
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="102" height="30" uuid="795dac43-0ff0-482c-89a0-7dac3b27d513"/>
                                <textElement>
                                    <font size="10"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[Profil]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="table_TD" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                            <box>
                                <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                            </box>
                            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="102" height="30" uuid="195d51a0-9e45-4201-ad67-d3026ce2e72c"/>
                                <textElement>
                                    <font size="10"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{profil}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="131" uuid="d36e39c4-8408-4f2f-865f-787aa3166a7e">
                        <jr:columnHeader style="table_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                            <box>
                                <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                            </box>
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="1" y="0" width="130" height="30" uuid="795dac43-0ff0-482c-89a0-7dac3b27d513"/>
                                <textElement>
                                    <font size="10"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[Taux de réponses correctes]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="table_TD" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                            <box>
                                <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                            </box>
                            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="131" height="30" uuid="195d51a0-9e45-4201-ad67-d3026ce2e72c"/>
                                <textElement>
                                    <font size="10"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{tauxCorrect}+" %"]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="103" uuid="d36e39c4-8408-4f2f-865f-787aa3166a7e">
                        <jr:columnHeader style="table_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                            <box>
                                <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                            </box>
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="103" height="30" uuid="795dac43-0ff0-482c-89a0-7dac3b27d513"/>
                                <textElement>
                                    <font size="10"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[Progression Moyenne]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="table_TD" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                            <box>
                                <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                            </box>
                            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="103" height="30" uuid="195d51a0-9e45-4201-ad67-d3026ce2e72c"/>
                                <textElement>
                                    <font size="10"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{progres}+" %"]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                </jr:table>
            </componentElement>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

--EDITED --

Here is the error full stacktrace :

```
  Compiling to file... C:\rapports\UserDepartTeste.jasper


net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRValidationException: 
Report design not valid :  1. Parameter not found : color     
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRAbstractCompiler.verifyDesign(JRAbstractCompiler.java:271)     
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRAbstractCompiler.compileReport(JRAbstractCompiler.java:153)     
at com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.compiler.IReportCompiler.run(IReportCompiler.java:512)     
at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:572)     
at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:997)
Compilation running time: 31!
```

Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Is it a full stacktrace?

Comment: do you need the error stacktrace ? or do you mean is that the full code ? if what you mean is second then yes it is the full code .

Comment: It was something wrong with your template. I reproduced the problem with your template. After that I've deleted the parameter `color` and create it again. And now it is ok. Maybe it was a problem with encoding...  Maybe the one part of the name was written on English and another one - on another language (Spanish?)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the style in the `<jr:table>` that is using a  `<subDataset>`, hence you **do not have direct access** to your main report parameter, you need to create the parameter in this `subdataset`

```
<subDataset name="New Dataset 1" uuid="2c012e5d-0895-4ef1-8b47-20fd8c6b281f">
    <parameter name="color" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="nom" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="prenom" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="profil" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="tauxCorrect" class="java.lang.Float"/>
    <field name="progres" class="java.lang.Long"/>
</subDataset>
```

and then pass the parameter when you call the the `jr:table`

```
<jr:table xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail">
    <datasetRun subDataset="New Dataset 1" uuid="7fc961fa-4d60-4d02-8145-f6cbfb54cc10">
        <datasetParameter name="REPORT_DATA_SOURCE">
            <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{DS1}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
        </datasetParameter>
        <datasetParameter name="color">
           <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{color}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
        </datasetParameter>
    </datasetRun>
    ....
</jr:table>
```

Comment: It worked like a charm :) , but i have now a new error that doesn't make sens `Error evaluating expression : Source text : $P{color}.equalsIgnoreCase("o")` in the `<conditionExpression><![CDATA[$P{color}.equalsIgnoreCase( "o" )]]></conditionExpression>`

Comment: It could have if $P{color} is null try "o".equalsIgnoreCase($P{color})